# Split file by date and keep header in Bash

Tags: bash, split

I need to split a TSV file by date using whatever standard CLI tools come with OS X 10.10; e.g. sed, awk, etc. FYI the shell is Bash

The input file has a header row and follows a tab separated format (the date and time is in the first column) — I'm adding "\t" bellow to show the tabs, and "…" to indicate the rows have many more columns:

```
Transaction Date\t Account Number\t…
9/16/2004 12:00:00 AM\t ABC00147223\t…
9/17/2004 12:00:00 AM\t ABC00147223\t…
10/05/2004 12:00:00 AM\t ABC00147223\t…
```

The output should be:

1. A separate file for each unique **year AND month** (based on the example above I would get 2 output files: 9/2004 and 10/2004)
2. Maintain the first/header row of the original file
3. Filename in the form YYYYMM.txt

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awk is the right tool for the job - do some research, make an attempt to use it yourself, then [edit] your question to show where you're stuck if you have any problems.

Comment: Should your output files only contain 1 row and will that be the same `Transaction Date\t Account Number\t..` for all output files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do pure in bash shell do as below...

```
#!/bin/bash

datafile=inputdatafile.dat
ctr=0;

while read line
do

  # counter to keep track of line number
  ctr=$((ctr + 1))

  # skip header line for processing
  if [[ $ctr -gt 1  ]];
  then
      # create filename using date field present in record
      vdate=${line%% *}               
      vday1=${vdate%%/*}              
      vday=`printf "%02d" $vday1`     # day with padding 0
      vyear=${vdate##*/}              # year
      vfilename="${vyear}${vday}.txt" # filname in YYYYMM.txt format

      # check if file exists or not then put header record in it
      if [ ! -f $vfilename ]; then
        head -1 $datafile > $vfilename
      fi

      # put the record in that file
      echo "$line" >> $vfilename
  fi

done < $datafile
```

Not sure how big your data files are but its never a good idea to parse large files using shell scripting instead use other utils like awk, sed, grep, etc for it.

For big files and using nawk / gawk one-liner use as below ... it will do all you need.

```
# use nawk or gawk if you don't get the expected results using awk
$nawk '{if(NR==1)h=$0;} {if(NR>1){ split($1,a,"/"); fn=sprintf("%04d%02d.txt",a[3],a[1]); if(system( "[ ! -f  " fn " ] ")==0)print h >> fn; print >> fn;} }' inputdatafile.dat
```

Comment: Thanks @narendra! That works!! — I also edited my question to make it clearer that I'm happy (actually prefer) to use standard tools. I was only meaning to say the shell is Bash — not that I specifically wanted a bash script. Question: can I say you answered my question without closing it so that I can get other suggestions with awk, sed, etc. (because I will need to process large files). Thx!

Comment: I modified my answer to provide the same using awk also.

Comment: You double rocked it! I used the awk version of your second suggestion and it also worked like a charm!

Comment: Actually — I got carried away. When I then cat the resulting files I discovered that with awk it stopped after line 41 of 750 line file… I can't tell why either… The last good line starts with: 10/10/2007 12:00:00 AM and the next line is: 11/9/2007 12:00:00 AM. And on OSX I don't have nawk or gawk…

Comment: I don't see any reason in awk code for it to stop on line 41 unless some issue with data file...try with different files and see if your issue persists and if there is any common behaviour of error.